# GCP workload identity fails to execute Workflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, workload-identity

I want to execute a GCP Workflow with a workload identity (WI) for AWS.

I have done the following:

1. create a WI pool for AWS with all default settings (no attribute condition specified)
2. create a WI provider without any attribute conditions
3. attach a service account with Workflow Invoker role and Workload Identity User role to the WI provider
4. run the below command

```
gcloud workflows execute test \
--call-log-level=log-errors-only \
--location=asia-northeast1
```

This fails with

```
ERROR: (gcloud.workflows.execute) There was a problem refreshing your current auth tokens: HTTPConnectionPool(host='169.254.169.254', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x104ca6520>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out'))
```

What is the problem here? I have already confirmed that the service account itself can successfully run the command.

Comment: It sounds like an issue on the AWS side, it seems you can't get the AWS token to perform the WIF. Did you try a command to simply list the workflows (not execute them), just to be sure that is not related to the execution.

Comment: Yes, I even tried `gcloud workflows list` after giving the corresponding service account the Owner role. It fails with the same error

Comment: Ok, it sounds be a AWS error. And I'm not an AWS expert. You could tag this question as AWS, to attract the AWS expert to help you!

Answer (score 0):

This happened because I was using my local terminal to execute this command.
The error message says

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='169.254.169.254', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone
```

which means it cannot connect to the URL `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone`.

This in turn is the URL for EC2 instance metadata, which GCP uses to retrieve the region for that EC2 instance. This URL is only available within an EC2 instance, and attempting to connect to this URL from my terminal will cause a time out.

To fix this, you can do the following:

- edit the credential JSON and remove lines for `regionUrl` and `Url`
- export the following 2 environment variables: `export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<your-access-key-id>` and `export AWS_REGION=<your-aws-region>`

Now GCP will not use the instance metadata URL and you should stop seeing the timeout error.